# Call a variable from inside a function into another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, global-variables, local-variables

I am trying to call a variable from inside a function into another function. I am running the code on node js and it's not working. Meanwhile, when I am trying the code on jsfiddle, it running normal. Any suggestion? thanks

```
var array = [];
 
function first(){  
     
array.push(3);
    
}

Function second(){console.log(array);}

first();
second();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change Function to just function. the `function` keyword is case sensitive.

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/qw7or2cg/1/

```
var array = [];
 
function first(){  
     
array.push(3);
    
}

function second(){console.log(array);}

first();
second();
```

Comment: Most welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is the code you used in Node, remember that Javascript is Case Sensitive, you wrote "Function" instead of "function".
Try:

```
var array = []
function first() {
  array.push(3)
}
function second() {
  console.log(array)
}
first()
second()
```